# cannot see the local commits on git status

Tags: git, github

Help, please ~

I encountered a question that I cannot see the local commits on `git status` after i add&commit my files,

```
$ git status
# On branch gh-pages
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

as we know, normally I should see a message on `git status`, for example,

```
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
#   (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
# nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

now there is no `(use "git push" to publish your local commits)` message to remind me.

But I can push them on github successfully,

```
$ git push
Username for 'https://github.com': <hidden>
Password for 'https://<hidden>@github.com':
Counting objects: 7, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 1.06 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://github.com/<hidden>/xxx.git
 f4a2f13..c6b5492 gh-pages -> gh-pages
```

Comment: May be you have more than one branch please check your current branch!

Comment: yes, I have two branches, master and gh-pages, i double checked my current branch is gh-pages. and it's also showed on my first above code.

Comment: I think git push method will push default master branch please check that might be the problem

Comment: I checked gh-pages and master on github, the latest commit is right on gh-pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you switch from master to gh-pages, is it telling you its up to date with origin/gh-pages ?

If not, have you set up an upstream branch tracking?
if its a new branch do

```
git push -u origin gh-pages
```

Keep in mind that message only shows when your local branch is either ahead or behind remote branch, (when doing git status), when you switch from a branch to another it should tell you if it's behind, ahead, or even.

Comment: Thanks Maor! it works! it's because i didn't set up the upstream branch tracking. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

`git status` will not show you commits

Use `git log` for that.

Comment: maybe i didn't clarify my question clear, Ruslan. i mean, normally I should see the message on git status, for example, # Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
#   (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
, but now I can't see that message.

Comment: can you try `git status --branch`?

Comment: `gh-pages` was a new branch, wasn't it?

Comment: yes, gh-pages was the new one, and i tried `git status --branch`, it is said, `$ git status --branch
# On branch gh-pages
nothing to commit, working directory clean`

Comment: That is the reason. `gh-pages` will be compared with `origin/gh-pages`

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply! Ruslan. I tried Maor's answer, now it works! it's because i didn't set up the upstream branch tracking.